# How to extract a value of a http xml answer using android java

Tags: java, android, xml

Well I'm kinda new to android and I'm trying to get a value of a http answer. But I never worked with that XML stuff before.

Example of web service : http://freegeoip.net/xml/123.123.123.123

this is the result here

```
<Response>
<Ip>123.123.123.123</Ip>
<CountryCode>CN</CountryCode>
<CountryName>China</CountryName>
<RegionCode>22</RegionCode>
<RegionName>Beijing</RegionName>
<City>Beijing</City>
<ZipCode/>
<Latitude>39.9289</Latitude>
<Longitude>116.388</Longitude>
<MetroCode/>
</Response>
```

how to get the value of countrycode, regioncode etc...

Comment: Search for *XPath*, it should help you.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun give an example

Answer (score 0):

You should use SAX API (Simple Api for XML) to parse the xml from the webservice and handle it with the DefalutHandler class.Here's the documentation of DefaultHandler class: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html
and here's a nice tutorial from 0 which should help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334859/Parsing-XML-in-Android-with-SAX